# Best output file format for 3D model to Unreal engine 4

Tags: modeling, export, file-format, unreal-engine

I am creating models in Blender for a game in Unreal Engine 4.  What output file format is the best and I can use for this for commercial purposes?

Answer (score 3):

I use Unity, another game engine. It does accept normal .Blend files. However, I'm not sure about Unreal engine. I would recommend .fbx as this is a sort of global file type for models like these.

Answer (score 3):

Most people use FBX when exporting to UE4 – you'll find a lot of information over at the [UE4 Wiki in the Blender Section](https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Blender)

Personally the only issues I've dealt with myself are:

- Importing meshes with millions of polygons (something you should not really do in a game engine anyway)
  takes a few minutes.
- Applying modifiers before exporting is a good idea as I've sometimes had some meshes in the .fbx missing when importing

There are also a few live-streams from UE4 that are archived on YouTube, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDP7GHFtAtE

Answer (score 2):

The best output format is the one recommended by the game developer. There is nothing from the Blender foundation that would affect use for commercial purposes, but elements of the game may be covered by other intellectual property considerations. For example, it is possible that the game developer trademarked elements of the game which could be infringed by the content you create in Blender. Consulting the game developer would be the best source of info on what might, or might not be infringing.

Comment: So in theory I can use any file format when I does it.

Comment: Perhaps. Only the game developer knows for certain.